# performance improvement in elixir when using lists

Tags: elixir

How can I improve the performance in, for example, a mergesort. In the merge step of the mergesort 2 smaller lists of size n/2 are combined into an list of size n. Because this is happening recursively the next tiem merge is called to merge 2 arrays, these lists have size n and the new list has size 2n. In Elixir lists are immutable I can't modify the values of the initial list, the list that I am trying to sort. Instead it creates new lists at each step of the merge. How can I improve this? Would one use ets?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid creating new lists but it's worth pointing out that prepending a new element to the list is cheap since it doesn't copy the old list unlike when you append to the list and that can probably be leveraged in this algorithm.

Comment: @JustMichael I was using the ++ operator which meant it had to iterate over the list and which is O(n) each time it did the merge. It's better to prefix the item to the head of the list and then reverse the list when needed.

Comment: Yes, exactly, reverse is highly optimized so it's better to do it this way

Answer (score 4):

Elixir has a lot of such performance issues aready solved. Taking for example this problem with merging in mergesort, we aready have `:lists.merge` that is taking presorted arrays, and returns one sorted array. Complete merge sort could look like this:

```
defmodule Sort do
  def merge_sort(input) when length(input) <= 1 do
    input
  end

  def merge_sort(input) do
    splitting_point = length(input) |> div(2)
    { left, right } = Enum.split(input, splitting_point)
    :lists.merge(merge_sort(left), merge_sort(right))
  end
end
```

I wrote Elixir has a lot of things sorted, right? The mergesort is no exception. You can just use `Enum.sort` that uses mergesort under the hood, and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation of mergesort, for what it's worth.

Note that this is just an exercise. As Olaf said, [`Enum.sort/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort/1) (and [`:lists.sort/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#sort-1) underneath) already implements mergesort. The `merge` function here could be replaced with [`:lists.merge/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#merge-2) too. Those those are implemented in Erlang though, so it's nice to see a pure Elixir version.

Points to note:

1. When building up the merged list, prepend to the front of the list, and `Enum.reverse()` only once to avoid traversing the list for each addition.
2. For merging, once one side of the merge is empty, we know the rest of the unmerged elements are already sorted and can be appended to the result directly (with `++`).
3. There is no way to avoid the creation of intermediate lists as far as I know, due to the immutable nature of the language. This is why in-place algorithms like quicksort are not the default.

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  def merge_sort([]), do: []
  def merge_sort([_] = list), do: list

  def merge_sort(list) when is_list(list) do
    len = length(list)
    {a, b} = Enum.split(list, div(len, 2))
    a = merge_sort(a)
    b = merge_sort(b)
    merge(a, b, [])
  end

  defp merge([], b, acc), do: Enum.reverse(acc) ++ b
  defp merge(a, [], acc), do: Enum.reverse(acc) ++ a

  defp merge([a_head | a_tail] = a, [b_head | b_tail] = b, acc) do
    if a_head <= b_head do
      merge(a_tail, b, [a_head | acc])
    else
      merge(a, b_tail, [b_head | acc])
    end
  end
end
```